# Persistent authentication across UWP app and Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services, uwp

Building on the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19781657/3458840) I'm attempting to authenticate an MSA login on the client, and have it authenticate service-side as well. The difference with mine is I'm using the new WebAccount-related API's in Windows 10 instead of the now deprecated Live SDK.

So far I've got:

```cs
var provider = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync("https://login.microsoft.com", "consumers");

var request = new WebTokenRequest(provider, "service::wl.basic wl.emails::DELEGATION", "none");

var result = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(request);

if (result.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.Success)
{
    string token = result.ResponseData[0].Token;

    //This calls my custom wrappers around the Live REST API v5 and runs successfully with this token
    var acc = await LiveApi.GetLiveAccount(token);

    var jtoken = new JObject
    {
        {"authenticationToken", token}
    };

    try
    {
        //Shouldn't this work? but raises a 401
        await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, jtoken);

        //Alternate method? Also raises a 401 
        //await App.MobileService.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(token);
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in the comments, all I get are 401s.

As far as I can tell the application is configured correctly in Microsoft Account dev center:

- I'm using the client ID and secret from the same app in the Azure portal.
- JWT issuing is not restricted.
- Redirect URL is of the format `https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback`

Authentication works fine when I switch to use purely server-side authentication. i.e.

```cs
await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATED:
The token I get back in the WebTokenRequestResult is 877 characters long and does not appear to be in the JWT format, with the dot (.) separators and I'm quite certain that this is the issue. The following error gets logged in service when the client calls the code above:

```
JWT validation failed: IDX10708: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' cannot read this string: 'EwCQAq1DBAAUGCCXc8wU/zFu9QnLdZXy+...Zz9TbuxCowNxsEPPOvXwE='.
Application: The string needs to be in compact JSON format, which is of the form: '<Base64UrlEncodedHeader>.<Base64UrlEndcodedPayload>.<OPTIONAL, Base64UrlEncodedSignature>'..
Application: 2015-12-07T17:47:09  PID[5740] Information Sending response: 401.71 Unauthorized
```

What format is the token currently in? Can it be transformed to a JWT?

Still no closer to a solution, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone feel free to correct me, but it looks like RequestTokenAsync gets you an *access token* which you can't use to login the backend. You need an *authentication token* for that, and as far as I can see RequestTokenAsync doesn't get you that.

There's some info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx) about the tokens.

Comment: This is correct. Mobile Apps is not yet optimized for UWP - the SDK is targeted at 8.1 and can be used in UWP projects, but no changes to accommodate new features yet. We'll be working on updates for that.

Answer (score 0):

If people end up here searching for a solution for App Service Mobile, the update to MobileService. Then there is now a [solution](http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/)

The code replicated here is:

```
async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{
try
{
    return await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<string>("values");
}
catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
{
    if (e.Response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

// Calling /.auth/refresh will update the tokens in the token store
// and will also return a new mobile authentication token.
JObject refreshJson = (JObject)await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync(
    "/.auth/refresh",
    HttpMethod.Get,
    null);

string newToken = refreshJson["authenticationToken"].Value<string>();
App.MobileService.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken
    = newToken;
return await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<string>("values");
}
```

Hope it saves somebody time !